# How can i select a specific test session in Allure history?

Tags: pytest, allure

I would like to know how can I select a specific *test session result* in Allure report version 2.27.0.
Let me give your more detail on my workflow.

1. i execute `pytest mytest.py  --alluredir=allure-results/mytest_<YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS>`
2. I generate report `allure generate allure-results/mytest_<YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS> --clean --output allure-report/mytest_<YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS>`
3. I do confirm that i see my report
4. I loop on previous step and ensure to follow instructions described https://allurereport.org/docs/history-and-retries/ to create an history execution

Let's say that i have a run like:

- mytest_2024_03_19_08_30_00
- mytest_2024_03_19_08_40_00
- mytest_2024_03_19_08_50_00
- ....
- mytest_2024_03_19_10_55_00

I do confirm i can see the differents execution in 'trend' graph and last results in *Suites* and *Features by stories* for mytest_2024_03_19_10_55_00

Now i would like to focus on past execution like mytest_2024_03_19_08_40_00.
How can i do that ? I can go through each specific test case and click on 'history' but this is not what i expect.

Do you have a workaround for my need ?
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable links to previous reports in the history trend, you need to provide [executor.json](https://allurereport.org/docs/how-it-works-executor-file/) with the `reportUrl` property specified.